# Can you hide the tmux status bar when starting a program like vim?

Tags: vim, tmux

Some programs, like `vim`, look much better without the tmux status bar at the bottom.  I have already set up a key that toggles the visibility of the status bar, but it would be even awesomer if the status bar just disappeared whenever I started `vim`.

Does tmux support anything so wonderful as this?  Or could it be approached even from the `.vimrc` side?  I would prefer something more elegant than `alias vim='tmux set status; vim'` if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd VimEnter,VimLeave * silent !tmux set status
```

Comment: It isn't perfect! If you have two window in `tmux` and you'll run in every window `vim`, tmux status set off, and `on` at next `vim`.

You can't use seperate `status off` by `VimEnter` and `status on` by `VimLeave` because of reason above. I think you should check if vim running or not  (maybe via `ps`?) before run `tmux set status`.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the problem uzsoft said and the answer from chepner, the problem is solved with:
 `autocmd VimEnter,VimLeave * silent !tmux set status off`